# creating a circular route from distance in android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I would like to create a circular route from distance.
First, I get current position, and then create a circular route based on the specified distance.
But I don't know how to achieve this at all.
I couldn't find any helpful methods in Google Maps API.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: My question has been solved already by using hubeny's distance formula.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily as Android Google Maps provides that API.

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Take a look at this official [Doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle).

The only change you need to make is to pass the current location's Lat/Lng to the center method.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/) to get the current location coordinates of a person.

Comment: Thank you very much, AniV.

But sorry, what I would like to do is to create a circular route, not to draw a circle. I'd like to create a circular-jogging-course.

So the shape of it is not always circle. It may be nearly square one or triangle one, if the route follow streets.

In Google Maps API, creating a route requires both starting and ending point. But in my app the starting point matches the ending one.

In this case, is there any way?